# ¿Por qué mi código CUDA C++ funciona sólo en mi GPU?

Tags: c++, linux, visual-studio, windows

Buenas tardes.

Estoy programando en lenguaje CUDA C++ usando Visual Studio 2015 en una GPU GeForce GT 540M bajo el sistema operativo Windows 7 y tengo un problema con mi código. Me basé en la séptima implementación propuesta en este documento para la suma de los elementos de un arreglo por reducción binaria: http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/1.1-Beta/x86_website/projects/reduction/doc/reduction.pdf

El código fuente de la función en el device con la que estoy teniendo problemas es el siguiente:

```
__global__ void reduccion()
{
    __shared__ double sdata[1024];
    unsigned int tid = threadIdx.x;
    unsigned int i = blockIdx.x * 2048 + threadIdx.x;
    unsigned int gridSize = 2048 * gridDim.x;
    sdata[tid] = 0;
    while (i < 307200) {
        sdata[tid] += g_idata[i] + g_idata[i + 1024];
        i += gridSize;
    }
    __syncthreads();
    if (tid < 512) { sdata[tid] += sdata[tid + 512]; } __syncthreads();
    if (tid < 256) { sdata[tid] += sdata[tid + 256]; } __syncthreads();
    if (tid < 128) { sdata[tid] += sdata[tid + 128]; } __syncthreads();
    if (tid < 64) { sdata[tid] += sdata[tid + 64]; } __syncthreads();
    if (tid < 32)
    {
        sdata[tid] += sdata[tid + 32];
        sdata[tid] += sdata[tid + 16];
        sdata[tid] += sdata[tid + 8];
        sdata[tid] += sdata[tid + 4];
        sdata[tid] += sdata[tid + 2];
        sdata[tid] += sdata[tid + 1];
    }
    if (tid == 0) g_idata[blockIdx.x] = sdata[0];
}
```

Y de la siguiente forma invoco el kernel de la función desde el host:

```
reduccion << <150, 1024 >> > ();
```

El arreglo con los datos está en la variable global `g_idata` dentro del device y es de tipo `unsigned char` de tamaño 307,200. El chiste es que toda la suma se hace de manera correcta en mi computadora.

Ahora estoy tratando de ejecutar el mismo código pero ahora en una máquina con Linux Mint 17 y una GPU GeForce GTX Titan Black y no siempre se hace la suma de manera adecuada. El código se ejecuta unas 70 veces. En algunas iteraciones todo el arreglo `g_idata` tiene un único valor diferente de cero, y en muchas de esos casos la suma me da cero siendo que nunca debería dar cero.

Estuve haciendo varias pruebas y estoy seguro el error está en esa parte del código y no estoy seguro por qué.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buenas tardes.

Ya encontré la solución a mi problema. En el documento que adjunté originalmente en mi pregunta viene escrito lo siguiente:

> Instructions are SIMD synchronous within a warp. That means when s <= 32 we don’t need to __syncthreads()

Parece ser este documento fue publicado hace varios años porque esa parte del texto no es del todo correcta. Al trabajar en la GPU más nueva, la GeForce GTX Titan Black, sí fue necesario el uso de la función `__syncthreads()` en cada reducción cuando `s <= 32`. Al corregir eso en mi código ahora sí funciona correctamente en cualquier GPU Nvidia con capacidad CUDA.